# How to see unbundled files to use in debugging for react native debugger?

Tags: react-native, react-native-debugger

I am using React Native Debugger to debug my react native app. When I go to the Sources tab I see the bundled javascript file that is being served up by the bundler server (Metro). I would like to see my original javascript files in source tab so I can set breakpoints etc without being in a huge bundled file that has been babelified. How can I do this? Thanks! [image]